# Getting : "Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress"

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, dismiss

1. A Swift 4 quiz app.
2. First view - select num of questions to solve. (use segue to second view)
3. Second view - start quiz ->checked answer and send "correct" or "wrong" msg to third view. (use segue way to third view)

When the third view appears I get the error:

> Attempt to dismiss from view controller <XXX.StartQuizViewController: 0x7fc893f09770> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

I've tried using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute:....
```

The warning message goes away but the problem is that I have no access to all the variables that I obtained from the second view for use in the third view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
        if self.answerStatus == "Correct!" {
            self.correctWrongStatusLabel.text = self.answerStatus
            self.praiseLabel.text = "Good job!"
            self.correctAnswerIsLabel.text = ""
            let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            self.fireTimer()

        } else if self.answerStatus == "Wrong!" {
            self.correctWrongStatusLabel.text = self.answerStatus
            self.praiseLabel.text = "Maybe next time!"
            self.correctAnswerIsLabel.text = "回答 : \(self.correctAnswerIs)"
            let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            self.fireTimer()
        }
    })

@objc func fireTimer() {
    delegate?.answerStatusReceived(answerStatusString: answerStatusString)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

After the second view appear with the quiz, when the user select an answer, it will checked it against the correct answer and display a response saying the answer is correct or wrong. the response view must automatically closes after displaying for XX seconds.

Comment: You should comment `self.fireTimer()` and there is no need to add delay using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {` so you can remove that also because you are scheduling a `Timer` and `fireTimer` will be called once the timer expires.

Comment: It did work when I removed the " + 1.0".
Why can't I just simply dismiss it:
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: How you are passing the variables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simply use:-- dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) and omit self

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't dismiss VC while in load, even if you add delay but no guarantee. Try add timer in viewDidAppear. Also, your `self.fireTimer()` doesn't necessary.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.answerStatus == "Correct!" {
        self.correctWrongStatusLabel.text = self.answerStatus
        self.praiseLabel.text = "Good job!"
        self.correctAnswerIsLabel.text = ""
    } else if self.answerStatus == "Wrong!" {
        self.correctWrongStatusLabel.text = self.answerStatus
        self.praiseLabel.text = "Maybe next time!"
        self.correctAnswerIsLabel.text = "回答 : \(self.correctAnswerIs)"
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    if self.answerStatus == "Correct!" {
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    } else if self.answerStatus == "Wrong!" {
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

@objc func fireTimer() {
    delegate?.answerStatusReceived(answerStatusString: answerStatusString)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the DispatchQueue method?

I would do it like this:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            if self.answerStatus == "Correct!" {
                self.correctWrongStatusLabel.text = self.answerStatus
                self.praiseLabel.text = "Good job!"
                self.correctAnswerIsLabel.text = ""
                let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                self.fireTimer()

            } else if self.answerStatus == "Wrong!" {
                self.correctWrongStatusLabel.text = self.answerStatus
                self.praiseLabel.text = "Maybe next time!"
                self.correctAnswerIsLabel.text = "回答 : \(self.correctAnswerIs)"
                let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                self.fireTimer()
            }
}

    @objc func fireTimer() {
        delegate?.answerStatusReceived(answerStatusString: answerStatusString)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I think you included the function FireTimer() inside the viewDidLoad method, so I would add a bracket "}" in the line before the function.

Let me know if it works! :)

Comment: It fires up the warning message right after the response view(third view) pops up.

Comment: simply use:-- dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) and omit self